# What is the actual difference between "dwell" to "live"?

Tags: word-difference

I didn't know the word "**dwell**" till today (maybe it says how common this word is), and after reading the [Cambridge dictionary definition of "dwell"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dwell?q=DWELL) (*to live in a place or in a particular way*) this word seems to me as a synonym of "live". Is that correct?

For example:

> I **live** in England.
>
> I **live** in five-room-flat.

Is in this cases the word "**live**" is interchangeable with "**dwell**"?

Comment: Remember, *flat* is a countable noun, so it has to be "in **a** five-room flat."  Also, there shouldn't be a dash (-) between "five-room" and "flat"; we don't join adjectives and nouns like that.

Answer (score 7):

Live is the normal word to describe a place where you habitually reside.

I live in London.

dweller is an anthropological and/or sociological word, and a literary word to mean reside.

-cave dwellers [those who live in caves]; city dwellers [those who live in cities]

**As a verb**, it would not be used as a substitute for live except in some literary or poetic narrative. It is rather archaic, also.

For example, in various passages in the Bible:

English Standard Version
Therefore thus says the Lord GOD of hosts: "O my people, who **dwell** [reside in] in Zion, be not afraid of the Assyrians when they strike with the rod and lift up their staff against you as the Egyptians did." ([Isaiah 10:24](http://biblehub.com/isaiah/10-24.htm))

Here is Emily Dickinson, a great American poetess:

> **I dwell in Possibility**
>
> I dwell in Possibility –
>   A fairer House than Prose –
>   More numerous of Windows –
>   Superior – for Doors –
>
> Of Chambers as the Cedars –
>   Impregnable of eye –
>   And for an everlasting Roof
>   The Gambrels of the Sky –
>
> Of Visitors – the fairest –
>   For Occupation – This –
>   The spreading wide my narrow Hands
>   To gather Paradise –

[*dwell* in Dickinson poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/52197/i-dwell-in-possibility-466)

Answer (score 2):

**Dwell** is more specific than *live*; it means something like "to remain *in one specific place*".

For example, it would be correct to say

> He dwells in Folkestone.

but not

> He may only dwell to the age of fifty.

In your examples, *dwell* is correct.  [It is not very common and sounds old-fashioned, though.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dwell%2Cdwells%2Cdwelt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdwell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdwells%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdwelt%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: So are there cases in which even nowadays people would prefer to use this word?

Comment: That Folkestone example pushes the envelope a bit....it's sounds archaic and perhaps the kind of sentence a person with a poetic turn of mind might utter....

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to the other excellent answers:

Even though "dwell" as a verb meaning "live" is pretty archaic, we still do use the phrasal verb "dwell on" quite often. It means to spend a lot of time thinking or talking about something.

> A: I can't believe how much I embarrassed myself in that presentation!
>
> B:  You made some mistakes, but stop dwelling on it. It's over!